# Correcting an error in liquibase script

Tags: liquibase

I have a long set of liquibase changesets. One of them creates a MySQL procedure and I just found out that this procedure will not be created and the whole liquibase script will consequently fail on MySQL, unless a specific MySQL option is set (log_bin_trust_function_creators=1).

Now, the changeset that created this procedure is deep in history. What is the right approach to changing it ? Mind, adding a new changeset that would fix the procedure will not help, because the whole processing fails on the old one. I have about 100 servers with databases managed by this liquibase script. I actually do not need to fix them, I just need to change the script (for the sake of future servers) and not break the existing servers next time liquibase will update them.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the code of the existing (invalid) changeset to a correct one and add runOnChange="true" into it's attribute, so if it is applied to a new server the correct procedure will be applied since the beginning, and if you apply it to the old server it will be just fixed?

Comment: Well, the procedure already exists on the old server, so trying to recreate it will result in an error, right ?

Comment: Can't you put 'create or replace' into sql procedure so it will just rplace existing one?

Comment: The "or replace" modifier does not seem to work with functions and procedures, according to docs of mysql 5.7

Comment: I have not hands-on experience with mysql stored procs but maybe you can drop it if exists (http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/126312/is-there-an-alternative-to-create-or-replace-procedure-in-mysql) ore check if it exists using liquibase sql precondition?

Comment: Well, the dropping would mean adding a new changeset, into the stream, which I think would break upgrades. As for preconditions, maybe that is the true answer. Is preconditions the right way of handling mistakes in liquibase history ?